# Does a flame produce free electrons?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, heat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Fire Conduct Electricity? Why?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/45105/does-fire-conduct-electricity-why)
>   [Is fire plasma?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23469/520)

Does a flame produce free electrons ? Or is the answer sometimes depending on the chemicals ? Does the answer depend on the exact heat ?
Does a (strong) magnet influence a flame ? Can that be seen ?

Comment: My apologies for the duplicate. I was unaware.