# Does fire have mass and weight?

Tags: energy, mass, matter, states-of-matter

What exactly is fire, why isn't it defined by the three states of matter, and does it have mass, weight?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is fire plasma?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23469/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9708/

Comment: [Fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire) is not a state of matter, it is what you see during a combustion process. (BTW there are [four](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_(physics)) states of matter).

Answer (score 2):

Quite a vague question, and I'm not sure its appropriate for the site. But, very simply, fire is glowing gases.

Gases have mass as they are made up of atoms, but the photons (the light and heat) that are radiated don't have mass.

Think about an analogy to a filament lightbulb. The heated metal which is emitting has mass, but the photons being emitted, for the purposes of this discussion, have no mass, just energy.